# How to copy github code to s3 bucket using only aws codebuild service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-codebuild

I want to copy a latest code of gitHub into amazon s3 bucket with the help of only code build service.

I know it's pretty much straight forward to do using codepipeline and codedeploy service. But I am more interested to see how its doable only with the codebuild service.

At the moment, I do not have any kind of java/scala/node js code in githib repository and also do not want to execute compile,run or test the code. I just simply looking to copy files from github to s3 bucket when there is PUSH event occured.

Please guide me ,how to configure codebuild service for this use case.

Please share your thoughts and links with respect to this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please take a look on this docs:

[CodeBuild - GitHub webhooks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-github-pull-request.html)

[CodeBuild Artifacts](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/getting-started-cli-output.html)

The main idea:

You can create webhook from GitHub to CodeBuild.
Every PUSH in GitHub it will start a CodeBuild container.
This container get the artifacts (repository).

In the CodeBuild itself you already have access to the artifacts so for example you can use boto3 (Python)/aws-cli to interact with s3 bucket and upload the artifacts.

Comment: Thanks @saggi for giving reply. Would you please share more details about builspec file. I meant, how my buildspec file will look like ? I don't get your second point about boto3.  Could you please explain that more in detail?

Comment: Does container will have latest copy of github code? If yes, then whats the default location to store github code inside container?

Comment: It depends in which lang u coding. i for example use python and for python boto3 is the AWS SDK(interact easily with aws services).

Simple explanation:
First you must create CodeBuild project.
CodeBuild is a container and the commands it will run is from buildspec.yaml.

You can provide this file in the CodeBuild configuration when u create the project:

1. path to file that store in s3.
2. hardcoded yaml.
3. path to file store in your repository.

see docs: 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/getting-started-create-build-project-console.html

Comment: And yes every PUSH that start your CodeBuild project, the project will get the latest code you pushed to the repository.

Comment: Hi saggi, Thank you  for your reply. I am thinking to specify aws s3 sync . s3://bucket_name command inside buildspec file. Is that correct option to do?. I believe code build runtime environment does not have aws credentials access by default. Could you please share the link with me which talk about how to setup  aws credentials for build env?

Comment: for creds just create an IAM role and assign it to the CodeBuild project. 
In this role you suppose to allow access to s3 (read/write/etc...).

I don't know if sync operation is the best one but it will work for you.
I almost sure you can put under artifacts section in the buildspec to which bucket output this artifacts.

Read this docs carefully: 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html

Answer (score 4):

I have followed below links to achieve this task.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/getting-started-create-build-project-console.html

I managed to copy the github latest code to s3 bucket by specifying below command to the buildspec file.

**Note**: Initially, I was under impression that I will need to configure aws cli but that's not the case here. It's already been configured within codebuild environment.

**buildpsec file**
[image]

**Note**: Make sure you have added enough permission(i.e. s3 read and write) to the codebuild default **service role**  as below.
[image]